# Cannot log into Unity with nvidia-current

Tags: unity, nvidia

I just installed natty from scratch. If I use the nvidia-current driver, I cannot login. The unity bar loads on the left, but the status area never comes up and the UI never becomes responsive.

If I downgrade to nvidia-173, I am able to log in. The only problem I seem to have with nvidia-173 is that if I switch to the tty (ctrl+alt+f1) and switch back, the graphics are horribly corrupted. The applications re-draw but the backgroud is permanently corrupted.

Any ideas on the issue?

lspci output for my card:

```
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation G71 [GeForce 7300 GS] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device c437
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at fb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at fc000000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia-current, nvidia-173, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be helpful for solving your problem:

It is a similiar problem like mentioned here (with a workaround): Geforce Go 7300/7400 blacklisted, can I still run Unity? [Geforce Go 7300/7400 blacklisted, can I still run Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39681/unity-geforce-8400-gs-support/39693#39693)